# Translate animation to correct position in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have created an animation for an image in my application. The image starts coming from the  middle till the top left corner of screen. Now I need to make sure that the image get placed at the right position in all the devices which is at the top left corner.
Currently it gets placed at different positions for different devices at the top left corner. How can I fix it ?
I have my code as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-36%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-30.9%p"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true" />
</set>
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got some pretty good results with this, so hope this helps you or any one. The idea is simple.

Position what you want to animate to **it's final position via xml** then I use `TranslateAnimation` and set its **from values** to any float values and **to values** as **0**. In this way the widget/view animates and comes to rest in the place where you have positioned it in xml.

A small example to animate a `TextView` from outside the screen to its position specified in xml.

```
//This is just for getting the from value, from where animation starts.
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();

Animation  moveRighttoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(width, 0, 0, 0);
moveRighttoLeft.setDuration(700);

AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
animation.addAnimation(moveRighttoLeft);
myTextView.setAnimation(animation);
```

Here are the xml's

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a Text View"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
```